# Can I check what files another person has checked out in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

My boss has gone on holiday for 2 weeks, and fixed a problem before he left but didn't check it in. I have found one file on his computer that seems to fix the problem, but I want to know if he has anything else checked out in case it takes more than the one file for the fix. Without looking through all the files individually, is there a way so see what he as checked out (like the pending changes, but for another user)

Comment: Which version control system? TFS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using TFS. You can do this through visual studio.

- Under source control explorer right click on the directory you are interested in.
- Go to find in `source control > Status` then you can enter a user to search by or just click find and you will see all checkout files.

Comment: Unfortunately my edit was rejected, thus now added as a comment: This approach requires the TFS Power Tools. Only then there's the context menu entry `Find in Source Control > Status` where you can select `Find`. See https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2009/08/04/see-and-possibly-unlock-files-are-checked-out-by-others/