# TFS - How to see all files checked out by a specific user?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfvc

I am working on a solution (a very big solution), and I want to check if I have left anything checked out. How do I see all the items I have checked-out?

And could you also tell me how to see all checked-out items by another user please.

Comment: Just to verify that viewing Pending Changes does show what files you have checked out. And to see everyone else's you simply go on Source Control, right click on the solution/file you want to check, (Find Source Control > Status), have 'Display all checked out' option on and click find. You will see everyone who has checked out items, if you want to find a specific user, just sort-order the user tab at the top and find them that way. Easy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply pull up the pending changes window (View > Other Windows > Pending Changes) to see what files you have checked out!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181395(v=vs.100).aspx

As for the other users, you would need to view the source control window to see who has checked out that file.
Simply go to View > Team Explorer then browse to the collection/project you are working on and double click on "Source Control" to open the source control explorer.

This then will show you the directory listing system where you can see who has checked out which file and what kind of check out.

also take a look at this: [Can I check what files another person has checked out in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027774/can-i-check-what-files-another-person-has-checked-out-in-visual-studio-2010)